# Can one deserialize a web response as it comes in chunks with Jil without thread blocking?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, jil

Deserializing a web response chunk-by-chunk is free as far as wall clock time is concerned, because waits for chunks are typically much longer than deserialization times. However, the existing solution:

```
var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream);
var deserialized = Jil.JSON.Deserialize<Result>(streamReader);
```

blocks the thread until the response is complete, which grinds the system to a halt in high concurrency scenarios. To use `Jil` with an asynchronous response read, we would need something like

```
var chunkDeserializer = new JilChunkDeserializer<Response>();    
chunkDeserializer.Consume(buffer, offset, length); //with baked-in string encoding
//chunkDeserializer.Consume(stringChunk); alternative with one extra allocation per chunk
```

with `var deserialised = chunkDeserializer.Finalize()` called when all data has been written. Is there something similar in Jil? If not, would it be possible to implement it? Moderate loss of performance would be meaningless due to it being absorbed by the chunk wait times.

Comment: Why not just asynchronously read the whole response and only call deserialize when that is done?

Comment: @Luaan This is what I'm doing at the moment. The downside is that you have to pay the extra time for deserializatition after the response has been completed. This matters quite a lot if you want to minimalize latency.

Comment: Well, you can't have your cake and eat it too :D If Jil doesn't fit your requirements, find another deserializer that does. And in fact, I wouldn't be surprised at all if the deserializer waited for all the data before doing any work anyway - have you measured this?

Comment: @Luaan In principle you can have your JSON and eat it too, because JSON deserialization algorithms are strictly sequential w.r.t. to the char array (or so I imagine, I may be wrong). I made only simple tests with deserializing the stream: that it doesn't scale and that with low concurrency it is faster than async reading the response and deserializing afterwards. It may be purely due to the overhead of async -- it doesn't matter for me anyway because of non-scalability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently possible with Jil, it can only deserialize complete JSON documents.

Speaking hypothetically: I'm not sure this would actually be any quicker either, because Jil would have to be able to stash its state (to subsequently resume) when it ran out of input.  Right now most of that state is on the stack, moving it out to the heap may cost more in runtime than you'd save.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have too smaller optimizations in mind, perhaps this comment is the best place to ask. Would it be possible to make an overload `Deserialize(buffer, length)` acting on a (complete) byte buffer with baked-in encoding? This would save an allocation of a sometimes big object. Secondly, would it be possible to make a deserialization target class definition with `StructPair<int,int> StartingIndexAndLength` member instead of a string member? This would save an allocation and be just as useful if one can work with sub-arrays.